# Disable ACS Web Api Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, acs

i'm using ACS in my WebApi project

when i try to open any page , i'm redirected to the authetication page (liveId, yahoo or gmail)

i want to disable the authentication for some pages or controllers

is-it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on your methods.

For example:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
}
```

You can read more about this attribute in this blog post:
[Securing your ASP.NET MVC 4 App and the new AllowAnonymous Attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx)